# Using javascript's TouchEvent with identifiers

Tags: javascript, mobile, touch

Javascript's TouchEvent is pretty fun to mess around with. However, there's one last thing I'm just not sure how to deal with. I'd like to make sure that "Touch #1" stops being confused with another Touch after the number of touches changes.

Example: you lay down two fingers on the screen. They are #1 and #2. In the `touches` array they are `[0]` and `[1]`.

Now you lift up finger #1. `touches` now refers to touch #2 as `[0]` when before it was `[1]`.

See my problem? How am I expected to make sure I am looking at the right unique identified touch?

I know each `Touch` is given a unique `identifier` number. Should I just build a search function that loops through all the touches inside  `TouchEvent.touches`  to see if my identifier is still there? Seems like a garbage collection nightmare. I'm hoping that there is a more sane way to use what's available, and I'm simply not sure what that is yet.